# Hadoop on ubuntu 12.04 " An XAttr name must be prefixed with user/trusted/security/system/raw, followed by a '.' "

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop-2.6.0 on my ubuntu 12.04 machine. I followed this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-hadoop-on-ubuntu-13-10

I set JAVA_HOME in .bashrc file and some configurations on these files:

1. /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
2. /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
3. /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml
4. /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml.template
5. /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml

When I try to type **"hdfs namenode -format"** I am getting this error:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15707750/

I search on google but I could not find a solution. 
Thanks in advance.